# WebGrid is returing an error "Column does not exist"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, webgrid

I have the following web grid inside my Razor view on asp.net MVC 5 and i am using Entity framework 6.0:-

Now the web grid is working well on all the paging except for one paging, and when i checked it i found that the `WebGrid` will return this error:-

> Column "SDUser.Department.Definition.DEPTNAME" does not exist.

So seems some items inside this page does not have those navigation properties `SDUser.Department.Definition.DEPTNAME`,, so how i can overcome this issue?

**EDIT:-** Here is my updated code, where i added If/Else but still i am getting the same error:-

Answer (score 1):

Before adding new WebGridColumn in gridcolumns, you check whether DEPTNAME property is there or not.

```
@if(@Model.Content.FirstOrDefault().SDUser.Department.Definition.HasProperty("DEPTNAME"))
{
    gridcolumns.Add(new WebGridColumn()
    {
        ColumnName = "SDUser.Department.Definition.DEPTNAME",
        Header = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content.FirstOrDefault().SDUser.Department.Definition.DEPTNAME).ToString(),
        CanSort = true
    });
}
```

Additionally, if you want to check its value is there or empty then use this

```
@if(@Model.Content.FirstOrDefault().SDUser.Department.Definition.HasProperty("DEPTNAME") && @Model.Content.FirstOrDefault().SDUser.Department.Definition.GetProperty("productSalePrice").Value != String.Empty)
{
    //your code 
}
```

Note: I don't know actually your hierarchy of Model, I consider that specific page has not DEPTNAME property. (you are free to modify according to your requirement)

Comment: ok i got your point, but what if the DEPTNAME does not exists, then do i still need to add an empty WebGridColumn ? as in this case the WebGrid will be corrupted, if some webgrid rows have less  columns compared to others, is my point/concern valid?

Comment: If DEPTNAME does not exist then you add the column with some default value "N/A " so while display it looks good also give info, for that particular row DEPTNAME value not applicable. you need to use then @if(){ }else{ } block

Comment: i updated my question, where i added If/else block but i am still getting the same error..

Comment: with or without else i will get the same error `Column "SDUser.Department.Definition.DEPTNAME" does not exist.`

Comment: that means SDUser.Department.Definition.DEPTNAME is bind with your webgrid from the anothor scenario, Debug your code from which place it added and add there specific condition

Comment: i did not get what u exactly mean, but when i debug my code inside VS the exception will be raised on this line of code  `@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns: gridcolumns

            );`

Comment: Debug gridcolums variable ,it might be contain deptname coulum. So check from which place deptname is added in gridcolumn..

Comment: Also try without if else and remove completly deptname webgrid column .dont add this webgrid column any place and check it working or not

Comment: Did you get a solution?